# JQuery attribute starts with selectors issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having an issue with JQuery attribute starts with  selectors `[name^="value"]`. below is what i am trying to do

```
var parentContainer = $('#myparent');
$.each(parentContainer.find('*[name^="a[2].b[0].c"]'), function(){
 alert('Hi');               
});
```

Though the parentContainer have the elements with name starts with `a[2].b[0].c` still not able to alert 'Hi'.

But when i try to do it as mentioned below it works

```
var parentContainer = $('#myparent');
$.each(parentContainer.find('*[name^="a[2].b"]'), function(){
 alert('Hi');               
});
```

need ur help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wWYfy/

Comment: The `*` in your selectors is superfluous.

Comment: @kei try putting 'a[3].b[2].c[0].d.e' as name attribute value. I have tried the same jsfiddle.net/wWYfy. Didn't worked for me.

Comment: @Manish Of course it won't work. That doesn't match `'*[name^="a[2].b[0].c"]'` It would, however, match `[name^="a[3].b[2].c"]`

Comment: @kei i am trying to find out all the input elements which has name attribute starts with a[3].b[2].c in an html node say form. '*' ll help me to go through each child node in the form and [name^="a[2].b[0].c"] ll filter those elems.

Comment: @kei don't mean the index i am using in expression 'a[2].b[0].c' those are just for example.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the responses to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

The following quote could show the cause of your problem:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Square brackets are not valid characters for `name` (or `id`) attribute values, and while it will often still work, you may get unexpected results in some browsers.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/pNLdH/) works fine for me in Firefox (only tried version 4), Safari 4 and 5, Chrome 12, IE8 and IE9 but fails (`undefined` is alerted) in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: But if i have to map the html input element to an array in my form or i have a complex form with nth level of hierarchy like MyForm contains an array of FormA which containes an array of FormB which contains an array of FormC which contains a FormD which has a String property e eg.'a[3].b[2].c[0].d.e', What should i do in that case if the square brackets are not valid.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow you. Are you asking for a new naming system? I would suggest using something like `a3-b2-c0-d-e` if you really can't just use a descriptive name.